# Correctness proof for algorithm to generate k bitsets of n bits (nCk)

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms, computational-mathematics

The problem is to generate all bitvectors of length `n` that have `k` bits
set. For example, generate all bitvectors of length `5` that have `3` bits
set. There are $\binom 5 3$ possible combinations, and they are:

```
# 1 | 0 0 1 1 1 
# 2 | 0 1 0 1 1
# 3 | 0 1 1 0 1
# 4 | 0 1 1 1 0
# 5 | 1 0 0 1 1
# 6 | 1 0 1 0 1
# 7 | 1 0 1 1 0
# 8 | 1 1 0 0 1
# 9 | 1 1 0 1 0
# 10| 1 1 1 0 0
```

#### The algorithm:

Begin from the state

```
#1           count of position
a b c d e    positions
1 1 1 0 0    bitset 
< - - - -    velocity
```

Where the `<` represents that the `1` at position `a` is moving leftwards.
Our arena is *circular*, so the leftmost `1` can wrap around to the right.
This leads to the next state

```
#2
a b c d e
0 1 1 0 1
- - - - <
```

We continue moving left peacefully.

```
#3
a b c d e
0 1 1 1 0
- - - < -
```

whoops, we have now collided with a block of `1`s. Not to worry, we simply
transfer our velocity by way of collision, from the `1` at `d` to the `1` at `b`.

I denote the transfer as follows:

```
#3
a b c d e
0 1 1 1 0  original state
- - - < -
- < < < -  transfer of velocity
- < - - -  final state after transfer of velocity
```

The `1` at `b` proceeds along its merry way with the given velocity

```
#4
a b c d e
1 0 1 1 0
< - - - -
```

Once again, it wraps around, and suffers a collision

```
#5
a b c d e
0 0 1 1 1
- - - - - < (collision, transfer)
- - < < < transfer of velocity
- - < - - final state after transfer of velocity
```

This continues:

```
0 1 0 1 1  #6
- < - - -
1 0 0 1 1  #7
< - - - - (collision, transfer velocity)
< - - < <
- - - < -
1 0 1 0 1 #8
- - < - -
1 1 0 0 1 #9
- < - - - (colision, transfer velocity
< < - - <
- - - - <
1 1 0 1 0 #10
- - - < - 
1 1 1 0 0 #11: wrap around to initial state
```

I don't have a proof of correctness. I feel like intuition might be possible, but I am not sure. Could someone help me with a proof strategy? Is this a known algorithm?

Comment: What will your algorithm produce for $1010$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will not work.  At any point in time, by the very definition of how you "transfer verlocity", you always have a contiguous (in the circular sense) block of $1$'s of length $k-1$ (or $k$).

In this example, you are lucky to get $10101$ which *looks* like three separate $1$s but in fact, in the circular sense, has a block of two $1$s.

However, if you try e.g. $n=6, k=3$, this method will never be able to generate $101010$.

Comment: Ah, cool :) thanks for the counter example!